# Drawing html with transparent background

Tags: html, css, qt, transparency, qpixmap

I'm currently trying to draw an HTML formatted text of a **QTextEdit** into a **QPixmap** with a transparent background, to use it as an overlay for another widget.

My first attempt was, to use the **QTextDocument** of the **QTextEdit** and use *drawContents()* to draw it to a **QPixmap**.

As a second attempt, I passed the HTML to a **QStaticText** and painted this to my **QPixmap**, using a **QPainter**.

Both approaches paint the final text as expected, however, the background of the **QPixmap** is always grey. Also setting the background-color of the **QTextEdit**, inside the StyleSheet, to transparent does no change.

Is there any way, that I can make the background transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, after some more research, I found the solution.

My **QPixmap** was not transparent at all, even before rendering the text. I came across [this blog post](http://qtdevnotes.blogspot.de/2010/04/transparent-qimage-or-qpixmap-picture.html), in which the composition mode of the **QPainter** is set to *CompositionMode_Source* using a call to *setCompositionMode()*.